# adjust multiple div display in parent div

Tags: html, css, angular, angular6, position

I have a div parent which contains multiple child divs but when it contains so many children I can't see all children because they stay in a single row, without do adjust into the column.

Here is my actual html

item1
                item2
                item3
                ...

```
            <mat-card class="hover tag" fxFlex ngxDraggable>item20</mat-card>
```

here is my scss:

```
.board{
  background-color:  #f5f5f5;
}

.board-header{
  background-color:  #f5f5f5;
  border-bottom: rgba(0,0,0,.87);

}

.tag{
  transition: box-shadow 280ms cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1) !important;
  padding: 10px !important;
  border-radius: 10px !important;
  max-width: fit-content !important;
  margin: 10px !important;
  max-height: fit-content !important;
}
```

Here is a kind of my actual result:

```
|                                    |
| |item1|  |item2|  |item3|  |item4| |
|                                    |
```

```
Here is what I expect:
|                                    |
| |item1|  |item2|  |item3|  |item4| |
| |item5|  |item6|  |item7|  |item20||
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `fxLayout="row wrap"` on your div container instead of `fxLayout="row"` (added wrap to make row wrap) does that give the result you expect?